# How do i parse the right panel direction text information?

Tags: google-maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SXpO.jpg)I refer the google maps direction api and write the code as below. The right panel direction informtion was fixed by google maps api. I want to parse the right panel direction informtion and display by my own method. How can i do it?

```
[<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Displaying text directions with <code>setPanel()</code></title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select, #right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

      #right-panel {
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        width: 390px;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      #map {
        margin-right: 400px;
      }

      #floating-panel {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
        display: none;
      }

      @media print {
        #map {
          height: 500px;
          margin: 0;
        }

        #right-panel {
          float: none;
          width: auto;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <strong>Start:</strong>
      <select id="start">
        <option value="25.0829642,121.5549714">美麗華百貨</option>
        <option value="25.0270954,121.572986">象山</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <strong>End:</strong>
      <select id="end">
        <option value="25.0270954,121.572986">象山</option>
        <option value="25.0829642,121.5549714">美麗華百貨</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="right-panel"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 23, lng: 122}
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

  var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
  control.style.display = 'block';
  map.controls\[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER\].push(control);

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC35ajFLVphL_1W-ZP3xKwVlgQxXNX_QYs&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse the panel.  Parse the [directions response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsResult) and use to create the format you want (that's what the DirectionsRenderer does in the panel).

See also [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults) for information about the directions results.